# Make variable of reference type non-nullable in C#

Tags: c#, null, nullable, reference-type, non-nullable

For example, I have a reference type variable that is guaranteed to be assigned

`string name = "";`

is it possible to make impossible this assignment?

`name = null;`

I heard of the `!` operator, but as I understand it is only to assure the compiler that the passed value is not null.

Comment: nullable reference types are just compiler static analysis - they're not enforced or anything. Beside that - `string name` is already non-nullable, `string? name` would be nullable. I'm not sure that i understand what your question is..

`string x = null` would give a cimpiler warning, `string? x = null` would not. Optionally you can do `string x = null!` to disable the warning.

Comment: @sommmen I'm probably bad with definitions and examples:), I mean that I want to make some reference type variable behavior with null similar to value type variable, I will rewrite my question with reference and value types

Comment: Maybe if you use in .csproj <Nullable>enable</Nullable> combined with <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>

Comment: @user1344783 yes, this behavior is exactly what I wanted, but due to <TreatWarningsAsErrors> there will be "side effects" I suppose